# How can I enter a directory (using cd command) and execute a specific file in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I need to connect redis server from my local machine . I have installed redis on my machine under the path: /Users/huangkunlun/Work/soft/redis/redis-6.0.10

If I enter the redis installation and run the command like following from my terminal,it will be successful.

```
cd /Users/huangkunlun/Work/soft/redis/redis-6.0.10/src 
redis-cli -h reids-host-server -p 6379 -a psw
```

but if i run the previous two command in shell script file,I got error displaying command redis-cli can not be found.

so the question is how can I enter a specific dir and execute the specific file under that dir from a shell script ?

the shell script file is like following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
REDIS_SRC_DIR=/Users/huangkunlun/Work/soft/redis/redis-6.0.10/src

HOST_TEST=redis-test-in.shantaijk.cn
HOST_DEV=r-uf61x52g8b0cketmk7.redis.rds.aliyuncs.com

env=$1
echo "environment is ${env}"

cd  ${REDIS_SRC_DIR}
echo "cd redis directory $(pwd)"


if [[ ${env} == "test" ]]; then

    #/Users/huangkunlun/Work/soft/redis/redis-6.0.10/src/redis-cli -h ${HOST_TEST} -p 6379 -a Cloudhis1234
    redis-6.0.10/src/redis-cli -h ${HOST_TEST} -p 6379 -a Cloudhis1234

elif [[ ${env} == "dev" ]]; then

    #/Users/huangkunlun/Work/soft/redis/redis-6.0.10/src/redis-cli -h ${HOST_DEV} -p 6379 -a Cloudhis1234
    redis-cli -h ${HOST_DEV} -p 6379 -a Cloudhis1234
else

    echo "no env args is  specified, exit..."
fi
```

Comment: Shell usually refuses to call programs from the current directory unless you explicitly tell it to do that. It's a security measure. Try `./redis-cli`.

Comment: @MVP : If you are already into to the path using cd , why their is need of again giving : `redis-6.0.10/src/redis-cli` . Just simply follow : @NO_NAME said it should work. And try to correct your code with shellcheck.net